# PHP MySql - Notice: Undefined variable Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Code For Show selected approved Items in Dropdonn Menu :

PHP:

```
  if (!isset($form['approved']) || $form['approved'] == '0')
     $approved0 = 'selected';
  elseif (isset($form['approved']) && $form['approved'] == '1')
     $approved1 = 'selected';
  else
     $approved2 = 'selected';
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="approved" class="formEditSelect">
     <option value="1" ' . $approved1 . '>Active</option>
     <option value="0" ' . $approved0 . '>Inactive</option>
     <option value="2" ' . $approved2 . '>Expired</option>
</select>
```

Now I see This error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: approved1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\edit.php on line 207

Notice: Undefined variable: approved2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\edit.php on line 207
```

How do i can fix This error?

Comment: you should declare first $approved1 and $approved2 = null

Comment: exactly and the reason is when the form is not posted `$approved1 and $approved2` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$approved0=null;
$approved1=null;
$approved2 = null;

if (!isset($form['approved']) || $form['approved'] == '0')
     $approved0 = 'selected';
elseif (isset($form['approved']) && $form['approved'] == '1')
     $approved1 = 'selected';
else
     $approved2 = 'selected';
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize variable first with blank or some values

```
$approved1 = '';
```

cause your vars in condition so default will be undeclared so initialize them first

or use check with  `isset()` or `empty()`
like :-

```
$approved1 = (!empty($approved1) ? $approved1 : '');
```

so your code will be

```
$approved0 ='';
$approved1 ='';
$approved2 ='';
if (!isset($form['approved']) || $form['approved'] == '0')
     $approved0 = 'selected';
  elseif (isset($form['approved']) && $form['approved'] == '1')
     $approved1 = 'selected';
  else
     $approved2 = 'selected';
```

Answer (score 0):

declare first `$approved1 = null;` and `$approved2 = null;` or `$approved1 = '';` 
you should first initialise these variables